# how to delete matched records in sqlplus command using joins

Tags: java, sql, sqlplus

delete t
from example1_tbs t left join example2_tbs s
using(department_name)
SQL> /

*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

it has same records in both the tables except few record i want to delete matched records of t as example1_tbs

Comment: Please format code correctly which helps in identifying syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether your database supports delete join syntax (not all do).  You could try using exists logic:

```sql
DELETE
FROM example1_tbs t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM example2_tbs t2
              WHERE t2.department_name = t1.department_name);
```

Comment: It is not supported, as mentioned here: https://www.databasestar.com/ora-00933/